# UITableView's reloadData sometimes does not call numberOfRowsInSection

Tags: ios, uitableview

`[tableView reloadData]` does not call `numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`

What i would write as an answer in stackoverflow if i saw a question like this:

- Be sure that delegate and dataSource is connected perfectly.
- Just in case check it if you are calling it from the main thread or not.

I tried my answers before asking the question.

I put the following line in my MyTableView class (extended from UITableView)

```
- (void)reloadData{
    NSLog(@"MyTableView (reloadData) self.dataSource: %@, delegate: %@, isMainThread: %d",self.dataSource,self.delegate,[NSThread isMainThread]);

    [super reloadData];

    [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(tableReloaded:) withObject:self];
}
```

I see that it is called from mainthread and datasource and delegate is never nil.

I am not curious about why tableView does not call cellForRow as it first has to call numberOfRows to see if the result > 0. However, it doesn't call numberOfRows too...

Any ideas? What can be the reason for tableView to giveUp calling numberOfRows function?

**Update:**
I've put new lines to reloadData function to print FullStack to see if it is being called from tableView's own functions. The result: They are called outside of the tableView so it there shouldn't be any unexpected behaviour.

**Update2:**
"Sometimes": I have discovered this problem after my users started to say that "sometimes" they don't see the changes in the table. After that, i tried to hit run button in XCode continuouslly until the app opens with this bug. (30% percentage of my runs shows this bug). When it happens, until i restart the application, reloadData never works again.

**Update3:**
I put `self.dataSource==myExpectedViewController` and also `[self.dataSource tableView:self numberOfRowsInSection:0]` to see if even delegates are not nil maybe they were being cloned etc.. The result was True and numberOfRows were correctly returning>0. So delegates are correct and i have more items than zero.

**Update4:**
I tried it with a fresh UITableView (removing my custom UITableView), i got the same results.

**Update5:**
I've put a button on the screen which recreates the table and sets its delegates. Whenever the problem in the question happens, i hit this button and everything starts to work perfectly. So, there must be something that breaks internals of UITableView which invalidates every call to reloadData, but i still couldn't find it.

Comment: If the `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` call returns zero, you wouldn't get a `numberOfRowsInSection:` call.

Comment: Can you confirm that `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` is being called and is returning > 0?

Comment: I haven't implemented numberOfSectionsInTableView (which should return 1), but now i implemented it and return 1 manually and put a NSLog to see if it gets there. Unfortunately, It doesn't get there too.

Comment: Did you set your table view's data source and delegate to this class?

Comment: In the question title, it says "sometimes". What is meant by "sometimes"?

Comment: @bobnoble I have discovered this problem after my users started to say that "sometimes" they don't see the changes in the table. After that, i tried to hit run button in XCode continuouslly until the app opens with this bug. (30% percentage of my runs shows this bug). When it happens, until i restart the application, reloadData never works again.

Comment: In the Update3 you are asking for number of rows in section 1 (per your earlier comment) - yet there is only one section.  Since sections (and rows) are zero based, shouldn't it be asking for number of rows in section 0?

Comment: @bobnoble I forgot to mention that my delegate's numberOfRows functions ignores tableView and sectionIndex (all parameters). It returns count from my singleton class. So it only includes something like this: `return [[MySource sharedInstance] itemCount]`

Comment: You say you are subclassing UITableView.  That's the thing that makes this different from the norm.  Have you overridden any methods where you should be calling `super` and haven't? Like `-init*` for example.

Comment: @SteveWaddicor I checked it now, i only have 4 methods: reloadData, touchesBegan, touchesEnded,touchesCancelled and all of these functions call [super ...]

Comment: Then it sounds like it would be easy for you to test using a standard UITableView instead of your own version. Do you still get the bug?

Comment: @SteveWaddicor using a fresh UITableView gave the same result.

Comment: Is the UITableView subclass or the datasource/delegate getting deleted early? (If ARC check by temporarily adding a dealloc method, without calling super, and put a breakpoint there).

Comment: @SteveWaddicor ARC is disabled in my app. I manually release objects. TableView and delegates are set inside xib file. I don't manually add or remove delegates. Also, as noted in Update3 of my question,my custom class' reloadData method checks the validity and correctness of delegate and dataSource objects (which are the same controller)

Comment: If it's not ARC then you already have the deallocs. Have you tried putting breakpoints or NSLogs there?

Comment: @SteveWaddicor i've put both NSLog and breakpoints to dealloc in MyTableView, delegate class to cells, almost every possible location. No luck.. I am somehow breaking internals of the UITableView but don't know how. (Because if i replace that table with a newly created UITableView with the duplicate properties and delegates, new table works perfectly.)

Answer (score 1):

**Edited** : I tried to replicate the issue and found, when I presented another viewcontroller on current view controller which has this tableview. and then 1. tried to reload this tableview with some data and 2. dismissed the viewcontroller which is on top of my currentviewcontroller with animation, simultaneously , then since in this duration, table view is not visible so it won't be reloaded.

To resolve, you can put a delay there or use completion block of that animation to reload table with effect.

Otherwise problem can be related to thread, UIElements are expected to be updated only on main thread.

During API calls and other process, we enters in other thread, and mostly we ignore to check whether we are on main thread before updating UIElement.

You should call yourTable.reloadData() in main thread using **DispatchQueue.main.async{yourTable.reloadData()}** and make sure it is being called on main thread.